# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

Tags: c#, powershell

I am writing a multi-platform c# command line application using .NET Core 3.1 that will need to work as a single executable. I am using Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.4). My OS is Windows 10.0.18363.778 and I intentionally did NOT install Powershell 7. I tested this first bit on my Windows and WSL Ubuntu and it worked until I added Powershell SDK 7. After I installed  Microsoft.Powershell.SDK 7.0.0 and when Ì set the project file as follows, everything runs nicely and I can validate I am using PS7 and not Windows PS.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, when I add the runtimeIdentifier in PropertyGroup:

```
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Build successfully completes without errors. However when I ran (both debuging or standalone) and application hits Powershell.Invoke, it throws a FileNotFound Exception with message:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified."

1) What am I missing to get all depdendencies in the executable directory?

2) When I add the following to create the single executable

```
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <UseAppHost>true</UseAppHost>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

It does not get created. I get the executable if I use:
"dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Debug"
but nothing happens when I run it. (This step used to work fine before PS7)
Is there anthing else I need to do to get the single executable running?

Comment: I know this is late, but changing the runtime identifier to win10-x64 would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and figured the following:
Answer 1: There is no Runtime identifer specific Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll files in the runtimes directory. Either Powershell SDK does not support all runtime identifers or its a bug. I will take it to github.

Answer 2: Running the single Executable file is misleading. My expected result was creation of a log file which is created in the application directory. I figured that when the single exe is run, it actually unzips ALL the files to the temp directory and runs the application from there (not the single executable) and hence the log file is not created where the single file executabe is.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem, you have to add this reference to your project. It take me 1 day to found this.

```
<PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="1.6.1" />
```